# Mac OS X - video call with iPhone 4 users

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mac, video, chat

Is there any application I can use on a Mac and people can use on their iPhones 4 to do video calls?

If beyond Mac OS X apps you can also mention Ubuntu Linux and WIndows apps that can do that too, I appreciate.

As far as I checked, skype is not an option.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple just released a beta version of [Facetime for Mac](http://www.apple.com/mac/facetime/). With it you can "make video calls to iPhone 4, the new iPod touch, or another Mac".

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that once FaceTime gets published, a host of existing applications will likely support it - Skype, Google Voice, iChat, and many more. This will also likely make its way to Android and Windows phones as well. Just a matter of time.

Comment: but beyond facetime... there's any application that can do that? I mean video calls between linux, windows, mac and iphone 4?

Comment: I think you misunderstood my answer. FaceTime is not just an application, it is a protocol. Other applications will likely support this protocol in the future, meaning that someone on a Windows PC could, using Skype with FaceTime support, make a video call to someone else with an iPhone 4.

Answer (score 0):

iMovicha, requires jailbreaking the iPhone but it works on all other systems including Android.